# Git - How to split a branch into 2 or more branches?

Tags: git

I've read some other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355904/how-to-split-a-git-branch-into-two-branches), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180511/how-to-separate-a-git-branch-into-2-other-branches), etc) , but didn't answer mine.

In the project I am working on there is a new rule: maximum 5 files changed/created per PR.
I know how insane is this rule and sometime impossible to do it, because to make a functionality work sometimes more than 5 files need to be edited/created.

However for now that's the situation and I need to understand a simple way, (maybe there is a software for it) to achieve for example the following:

1. From a branch with 8 files changed (compared to master)
2. Split it into two new branches, one with 5 files and the other with 3 files (of my choice)

Now matter if the new branches will not have the functionality working. Still it is needed, no matter how insane is that - not my decision :(

How to split such branch?

Thank you

Comment: Tomorrow, new rule, the 3rd char of each file can't be a space. On tuesdays.

Comment: The only way is to do separate commits, one commit has 5 files, the other one 3. Doing such things afterwards is always bad, because you should not change the git history. Create two new branches, with two separate commits. And in the future, you have to commit your files splitted. Git will not do this for you, and also no software will do this, beacause it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite entire histories by using `rebase` tool.

I'll show you an example of how you would do that. Assume your starting branch is `feature/big`.

Start by creating 2 branches, named `feature/small1` and `feature/small2` at the  same point:

```
git branch feature/small1 feature/big
git branch feature/small2 feature/big
```

Switch to one branch and remove some files/commit. You can use `--fixup` to remind yourself to squash the changes with a certain commit (or `--amend` if you want to change your last commit). Use `git log <filename>` to discover the commit id where the changes were made

```
git switch feature/small1
# remove file1 which was added on commit abcdef
git rm file1
git commit --fixup abcdef
# revert changes of file2 which was changed on commit 12345
git checkout file2 -- 12345^
git add file2
git commit --fixup 12345
```

Now squash the changes with the original commits where the changes were made, and push the new branch to the remote repository

```
git rebase -i --autosquash `git merge-base HEAD master`
git push feature/small1
```

Repeat with `feature/small2`, but this time remove different files.

Refer to [git rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for the explanation of what these commands do.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain the second example? `git checkout file2 -- 12345^` I usually use `git checkout branchname` to switch to a different branch.

What is this revert? What will file2 contain? If the `feature/small1` was created from `feature/big` the file `file2` is identical to `file2` in `feature/big`?!

Comment: if you provide a filename to `git checkout` it will get that file as it was at the commit specified, without switching branches or head. So this basically means "get the file named `file2` how it was in the commit `12345^`, (which is the parent of the `12345` commit)"

Answer (score 2):

You have my sympathy. Git handles everything at the commit level.

You can potentially take your feature branch, use `git reset --soft` to go back in the history and you can stage/unstage your changes to make multiple branches.